# iOS - when to remove subviews from UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uiimage, subview

I have a `UITableView` which a `UIImage` is added as a subview to each cell of it. The images are PNG transparent. The problem is when I scroll through the `UITableView`, the images get overlapped and then I receive the memory warning and stuff.

here's the current code for configuring a cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    int cellNumber = indexPath.row + 1;
    NSString *cellImage1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%i.png", cellNumber];
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:cellImage1];
    UIImageView *cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImage];

    return cell;
}
```

I know the code for removing the `UIImage` subview would be like:

```
[cell.imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

But I don't know where to put it. I've placed it between all the lines; even added an else, in the if statement. didn't seem to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` already have a image view attached. Remove:

```
UIImageView *cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellImage];
```

Add:

```
[cell.imageview setImage:theImage];
```

and you're good to go!

Result code will be like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%i.png", indexPath.row + 1]];
    [cell.imageView setImage:cellImage];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks!! it worked. however I still receive a memory warning when I scroll which causes a CRASH!! :( I have around 500 rows in the tableView. and I have no idea how to fix this. any ideas?

Comment: I guess the images need to get 'nil'ed somehow! I used instruments and when I scroll, the memory usage get's higher n higher.

Comment: `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` you should mention autorelease in creation of above line. So the correct statement is this: `cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];`

Answer (score 1):

You just kepp this:

```
 [cell.imageview setImage:theImage];
```

and remove:

```
UIImageView *cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellImage];
```